# Divide a Dword by a word nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, division, extended-precision

I'm trying to do a signed division of a dword in `DX:AX` let's say 1234567 with a word [b]=10.

```
a dd 1234567
b dw 10
mov ax,[a]
mov dx,[a+2]
idiv word [b]
```

The quotient should be 123456 but its too big so it doesn't fit in ax. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Use 64 bit division, if available. Otherwise, implement it yourself.

Comment: So I should convert the dword to qword and the word to dword and do the signed division?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @Jester So I've done like this:mov ax,[b]; cwd; mov [e],ax; mov ax,[a]; mov dx,[a+2]; cdq; idiv dword [e] . But this only divides eax by [e] ,because considers edx=0.

Comment: `mov eax, [a]` / `cdq` / `mov ecx, 10` / `idiv ecx`.  If you have 32-bit operand size available, you put all of `a` into `eax` like you would normally for any other 32-bit operation.  Then you use 64b / 32b => 32b division with the upper half of the dividend = 0.  (`cdq` sign extends `eax` into `edx:eax`.  To set up for `div` instead of `idiv`, use `xor edx,edx`)

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Was this meant to be 16-bit code or 32-bit code?

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have 32-bit operand size available, so use it for more than just `idiv dword [b]` (which reads outside of the 16-bit `b` and thus can't be right).

```
mov eax, [a]
cdq
mov ecx, 10      ; or  movsx ecx, word [b]  to load with sign-extension
idiv ecx
```

You put all of `a` into `eax` like you would normally for any other 32-bit operation. Then you use 64b / 32b => 32b division with a trivial upper half of the dividend (sign or zero extend).

`cdq` sign extends `eax` into `edx:eax`. To set up for `div` instead of `idiv`, use `xor edx,edx` to zero the upper half.